# Cannot find Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I am following tutorial in: 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-recurring-payments--net-30168

which is nice so far as I needed to get into sandbox.

Just can't find where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find sandbox inside PayPal. [SandBox](https://developer.paypal.com/) is a test platform for developers where you can simulate payments. If your code works in SandBox then it will work in production enviroment with PayPal.
You should register your developer account and begin to test.

[here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator) you can simulate IPN

Comment: Basically I want to test IPN endpoint, where I can do that in mentioned website?

Comment: Are you registered in paypal developers website? Once you register there you'll test what you want

Comment: I have a paypal business account and it logged me in that website as well. Where can I find something like "IPN simulator" mentioned in tutorial?

Comment: try with this link https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator

Comment: I was exactly looking for this: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/

but could not find a link, thanks.

Comment: Remembar to mark the answer as accepted (if it solve your problem) to avoid that the question remains unanswered